# Manipulation List of Matrices in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list of matrices, containing 100 matrices. `L[[i]]` is a square matrix of 200*200. I want to manipulate each matrix in `D-L[[i]]` format where D is a diagonal matrix with diagonal with diagonal as sum of `L[[i]]` over columns. I want something like

`for(i in 1:100){
 M_i = diag(as.matrix(rowSums(L[[i]]))) - as.matrix(L[[i]])
}`

So that now I can find manipulated `M_i` and further want to print each `M_i`. Thanks in advance for any help in this direction.

Comment: You may need `M_i` as  a list. i.e. `M_i <- vector('list', length(L))` and `M_i[[i]] <- diag(as.matrix(..`

Comment: Dear Akrun, Thanks for reply. It is not working. Probably I could not convey clearly. I need to change my matrices but `M_i[[i]]` becomes something like list of list. I want to modify each element of my list (every element is matrix ) and then print every modified element. Kindly help.

Comment: As I could understood, you suggested something like `for(i in 1:100){` `M_i <- vector('list', length(L))`
 `M_i [[i]]= diag(as.matrix(rowSums(L[[i]]))) - as.matrix(L[[i]])`
`}`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand it properly.  You said you want to change the matrices in `L` by the calculated value `diag(as.matrix(...`.  Wouldn't it be better to store the elements as a list?  or do you have something else in mind

Comment: You can define the `M_i` outside the for loop as well.

Comment: Yes.. My new list should look like `M[[1]], M[[2]], ...., M[[100]]` with `M[[1]] = diag(as.matrix(rowSums(L[[1]]))) - as.matrix(L[[1]])` and `M[[2]] = diag(as.matrix(rowSums(L[[2]]))) - as.matrix(L[[2]])` and so on... Which is not so.. Yeah I wrote wrongly above.. However I tried by keeping `M_i` outside the loop... Please help

Comment: So, what is the problem now?  It is a little unclear for me from the comments that whether it works or not.

Comment: Why do you have to convert to matrix again `as.matrix(L[[1]])`.  Isn't `L[[1]]` already a matrix

Comment: Dear Akrun, It did not work as my argument is `L[[1]]` is a matrix so effectively `M_i[[1]]` should also be matrix of same size, which is not so.

Comment: I posted a solution with a reproducible example.  Please check if that is the output you wanted.

Comment: Dear Akrun above worked when I remove `as.matrix`. I wonder how it did affect? Thanks for help. I voted you up and gave you the green. Kindly also tell me how can I store the eigen values of these new matrices.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Do you mean to save the output list into file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
lapply(L, function(x) diag(rowSums(x))-x)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(25)
L <- lapply(1:5, function(i) matrix(sample(1:20, 4*4,
         replace=TRUE), ncol=4))
```